# Unexpected program behaviour during execution

Tags: c

I have a 2 dimensional char array, and I want to count its words and characters. The array is initialized globally, so if im not mistaken any "empty" elements should be 0. The code works perfectly for the character calculation, but for words it returns M, which is the size of the whole array. (Array size is [M][N]). I'm a newbie so it could be something obvious that i'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

```
int i,j;

int wordCounter = 0;
for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    if (a[i]==0) break;
    wordCounter++;
}
printf("%d words.\n", wordCounter);


int charCounter = 0;
for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        if (a[i][j]==0) break;
        charCounter++;
    }
}
printf("%d characters without spaces.\n", charCounter);
```

Comment: Replace `a[i]==0` with `a[i][0]==0`. `a[i]` is an address to the beginning of that column/row (I can never remember which comes first), and "will" not be `0`.

Comment: Would be nice to see the definition of `a` to confirm what you are doing.  In C there is no auto-initialization of variables or memory so I would say that you are mistaken that any "empty" elements  should be zero, but perhaps the way it is initialized is doing something for that.